# SSIS OLE Destination several error output

Tags: ssis

I have a problem... 
I have an OLE DB error that occurred in INSERT statement than conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint. 
SSIS package eturn this  3 errors:

> [OLE_DEST PollOptionUserResult [43]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>       An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
>       An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_PollOptionUserResult_PollUserResult". The conflict occurred in database "dw_ismsES", table "ten.PollUserResult", column 'PollUserResultID'.".
>
> [OLE_DEST PollOptionUserResult [43]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE_DEST PollOptionUserResult.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE_DEST PollOptionUserResult.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE_DEST PollOptionUserResult" (43) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (56). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

When I try redirect error to my `error_table`, it internally for some reason take the last one and no the first one I need.

How I can obligate it to take the first one error?

Comment: What component/code are you using to redirect the error?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your error configuration?

Comment: You could put your error logic in an error event. So every time an error is created it will log to your error_table.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (SSIS 2008), I created an **OnError** event in the **package level**, so every error happening in the package would be logged, regardless of where they happened. When I take this approach, all 3 errors should be logged in my error table. I.e.

[image]

Please try this approach and see what you get.